# Convert a column with values in a list into separated rows grouped by specific columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to convert a column with values in a list into separated rows grouped by specifics columns.

That's the dataframe I have:

```py
id        rooms        bathrooms        facilities             
111       1            2                [2, 3, 4]
222       2            3                [4, 5, 6]
333       2            1                [2, 3, 4]
```

That's the dataframe I need:

```py
id        rooms        bathrooms        facility             
111       1            2                2
111       1            2                3
111       1            2                4
222       2            3                4
222       2            3                5
222       2            3                6
333       2            1                2
333       2            1                3
333       2            1                4
```

I was trying converting to list the column facilities first:

```py
facilities = pd.DataFrame(df.facilities.tolist())
```

And later join by columns and following the same method with another suggested solution:

```py
df[['id', 'rooms', 'bathrooms']].join(facilities).melt(id_vars=['id', 'rooms', 'bathrooms']).drop('variable', 1)
```

Unfortunately, it didn't work for me.

Another solution?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
df.explode('facilities')

#    id  rooms  bathrooms facilities
#0  111      1          2          2
#0  111      1          2          3
#0  111      1          2          4
#1  222      2          3          4
#1  222      2          3          5
#1  222      2          3          6
#2  333      2          1          2
#2  333      2          1          3
#2  333      2          1          4
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit awkward to have list as values in a dataframe so one way I can think of to work around this is to unpack the lists and store each in its own column, then use the melt function.

```
# recreate your data
d = {"id":[111, 222, 333],
    "rooms": [1,2,2],
    "bathrooms": [2,3,1],
    "facilities": [[2, 3, 4],[4, 5, 6],[2, 3, 4]]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

# unpack the lists
f0, f1, f2 = [],[],[]

for row in df.itertuples():
    f0.append(row.facilities[0])
    f1.append(row.facilities[1])
    f2.append(row.facilities[2])
    
df["f0"] = f0
df["f1"] = f1
df["f2"] = f2

# melt the dataframe
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['id', 'rooms', 'bathrooms'], value_vars=["f0", "f1", "f2"], value_name="facilities")

# optionally sort the values and remove the "variable" column
df.sort_values(by=['id'], inplace=True)
df = df[['id', 'rooms', 'bathrooms', 'facilities']]
```

I think that should get you the dataframe you need.

```
    id  rooms   bathrooms   facilities
0   111 1   2   2
3   111 1   2   3
6   111 1   2   4
1   222 2   3   4
4   222 2   3   5
7   222 2   3   6
2   333 2   1   2
5   333 2   1   3
8   333 2   1   4
```

Comment: It works perfectly if the number of facilities are always 3. But, if the number is less or more than 3, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The following will give the desired output

```
def changeDf(x):
     df_m = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id','rooms','bathrooms','facilities'])
     for index, fc in enumerate(x['facilities']):
          df_m.loc[index] = [x['id'], x['rooms'], x['bathrooms'], fc]
     return df_m

df_modified = df.apply(changeDf, axis=1)
df_final = pd.concat([i for i in df_modified])
print(df_final)
```

"df" is input dataframe and "df_final" is desired dataframe

Comment: It is too slow.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
reps = [len(x) for x in df.facilities]
facilities = pd.Series(np.array(df.facilities.tolist()).ravel())
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(reps)].reset_index(drop=True)
df.facilities = facilities
df

    id  rooms  bathrooms  facilities
0  111      1          2           2
1  111      1          2           3
2  111      1          2           4
3  222      2          3           4
4  222      2          3           5
5  222      2          3           6
6  333      2          1           2
7  333      2          1           3
8  333      2          1           4
```